# Re-sending email verification with Parse

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

I am not sure if I just did not see it or it is not obvious but is there a way for either **Javascript** **SDK** or **REST API** of Parse to re-send verification email to specific username/email that signed up and did not get the email for whatever reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I faced this issue few years ago and as far as I remember there was no way to resend the verification Email directly via the Parse SDK. The Email verification was being triggered automatically when the Email field was being populated first or updated.

As a workaround, I implemented a cloud function to overwrite the Email field to trigger a resend. The function stored the original Email address value in a temp variable and then replaced the Email field with a randomly generated valid Email address, then repopulate it again with the original Email address immediately. This used to trigger an Email resend from the Parse server.

The code was something like this:

```js
    var user  = request.user;
    var email = user.get("Email");
    var randomMail = "objectID@domain.com"; //// random but valid Email address
    user.set("email", randomMail); /// Populate the field

    user.save(null, { useMasterKey: true }).then( function(user) {

        // The field was updated, recover the original Email address again
        user.set("email", email);
        return user.save(null, { useMasterKey: true });

    }).then( function(user) {

        response.success();

    }, function(error) {

        response.error(error);
    });
```

Comment: I can not find a built-in function in parse server for re-send verification email even today :(

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5 and iOS**

For anyone still looking into this.  I'm using this code to have the server resend the email verification.

The following code I placed inside my User class as a function named verificationEmailRequest but you can place it wherever you need to get the email address needed.

```
   let json: [String: Any] = ["email": "<email address here>"]
   let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json)
    
   // create post request
   let url = URL(string: "\(Parse.currentConfiguration?.server ?? "")verificationEmailRequest")! //PUT Your URL
   var request = URLRequest(url: url)
   request.httpMethod = "POST"
   request.setValue("\(String(describing: jsonData?.count))", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
   request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
   request.setValue(Parse.currentConfiguration?.applicationId, forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Parse-Application-Id")
   request.setValue(Parse.currentConfiguration?.clientKey, forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Parse-Client-Key")
   // insert json data to the request
   request.httpBody = jsonData
    
   let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
    guard let data = data, error == nil else {
        print("error here: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "No data")")
        return
    }
    
    let responseJSON = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
    if let responseJSON = responseJSON as? [String: Any] {
        print("successful response: \(responseJSON)") //Code after Successfull POST Request
        
    }
 }
 
 task.resume()
```

This code uses the REST API from Parse server that send the verificationEmail. (See [here](http://docs.parseplatform.org/rest/guide/#verifying-emails))

Important to note that I'm using Parse.currentConfiguration for authentication which is freely available and needed to setup Parse with Swift anyway. It's usually placed in SceneDelegate.

I have no idea currently if it's a security risk to do it this way as I cannot find any reason Parse has yet to implement this function.